# How to configure fail-fast strategy for Zuul CI jobs for a specific project?

Tags: zuul-ci

How can someone configure a specific project (repository) to use a fail-fast strategy for jobs running inside it?

fail-fast strategy on CI means that you want to cancel any running jobs as soon the first one that counts towards final result is failing (saving compute resources and providing a faster feedback).

Please note that I explicitly asked about a specific project as this option should not affect other project that may have different preferences.

Answer (score 0):

The fail-fast option is already by design a per project (or per project-template) and pipeline setting [1].

e.g. from within an untrusted project:

```
- project:
    check:
      fail-fast: true
      jobs:
        - test foo
```

Or you can set it in a config project for a different project:

```
- project:
    name: org/other-project
    check:
      fail-fast: true
```

[1] https://zuul-ci.org/docs/zuul/reference/project_def.html#attr-project.%3Cpipeline%3E.fail-fast